# MVC - Validate form on click on input type button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have need to validat MVC form on input type="button" click, not on input type="submit".
On clicking on button need to validate form and fire related validations using javascript if value is invalid.

My form is like

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmationForPayment", "Plan", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" }))
```

I also tried with

```
 $('form#frm').validate();
 $('frm').validate();
```

but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your use client side validation you can try:

```
Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm($("#frm")[0]).validate('submit');
```